# ViewController.type does not have a member named 'wordList' Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to print a random element from a list in Swift but I keep getting a "ViewController.type does not have a member named 'wordList' error. I've tried to define the variables in the viewDidLoad() function but that means that I cannot access it in other functions.

This is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

var playerTurns = 0

var wordList = ["Watch", "Phone", "Apple", "Technology", "Swift", "Computing", "Software", "Hardware", "Computers", "Processor", "Swift", "Java", "Python", "Programming", "Development", "Microsoft", "DropBox", "Facebook"]


var wordToUse = wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))]
println(wordToUse)

wordLabel.text = String(wordToUse)
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid. Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

var playerTurns = 0

var wordList = ["Watch", "Phone", "Apple", "Technology", "Swift", "Computing", "Software", "Hardware", "Computers", "Processor", "Swift", "Java", "Python", "Programming", "Development", "Microsoft", "DropBox", "Facebook"]


    var wordToUse: String { 
      return wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))]
    }

    func printWordToUse() {
      println(wordToUse)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      wordLabel.text = wordToUse
    }
}
```

Declare wordToUse as a computed property of type 'String' and wrap your     `println()` call inside an instance method.
Then, in `viewDidLoad()`, make the assignment to your outlet.

If you want, you can create an IBAction from a button and then use the `printWordToUse()` method.

When declaring a class, you are basically just defining a **prototype**. This means that this is some kind of blueprint which tells everyone what particular instances of this class will be able to do as soon as they are created. So when defining a class, you can *just put properties and methods* inside the declaration.

So this call `println(wordToUse)` - which should be `println("(wordToUse)") is not a declaration of a method of property and thus results in a compiler error "expected declaration".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use instance variables in the declaration initialization (initialization when declaring them to be instance fields) of other instance variables. I would suggest performing that initialization in an `init()` method or in the `viewDidLoad()`.